# subspace of infinite dimensional vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

My question is Is it true that

if $X$ is infinite dimensional vector space and $P$ is subspace of $X$ and $P$ is isomorphic to $X$ then $P$=$X$

Comment: No.  The space of all polynomials over $\mathbb R$ is isomorphic to the subspace consisting of all multiples of $x$.

Comment: More abstractly, the vector space over a field $\mathbb F$ with basis $\{x_1,x_2,\cdots\}$ is isomorphic to the subspace with basis $\{x_2,x_3,\cdots\}$ with the isomorphism given by taking $x_i$ to $x_{i+1}$.

Comment: @lulu Why don't you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 3):

As requested in the comments:

The answer is no.

To see some examples, consider the space of all polynomials with real coefficients and let $P$ be the subspace consisting of those polynomials divisible by $x$.  Those spaces are isomorphic under the map $p(x)\mapsto xp(x)$.

More abstractly, consider the vector space over a field $\mathbb F$ with basis $x_0,x_1,x_2,\cdots$ and let $P$ be the subspace with basis $x_1,x_2,\cdots$.  These are isomorphic under the map which takes $x_i$ to $x_{i+1}$.

(Note:  using the basis $1,x,x^2,\cdots$ for the polynomials you can see that the first example is an instance of the second).